# W10: Macro assigned to change shortcut key of batch file(s) no longer work after PC reset. I want to automate this reassignment process

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, batch

I'm using Logitech G Hub to assign these batch files to my mouse's side buttons. Upon reset, the shortcut key assigned to the batch files doesn't work This is random, some shortcut keys respond, others need to be removed and added back. I would like to create another batch file that reassigns all macros to these shortcuts so I don't have to do it myself every time. Can anyone tell me how to do this?

Comment: When I reset my pc, it breaks the keybinds for the shortcuts I've made for the batch files. 

The reason I don't think it's Logitech fault is because I don't have to reassign the keys to the mouse. What I've found solves the issue is going to the Shortcut Properties, removing the Shortcut key, Applying and closing the window, then going through the same steps but adding back the Shortcut key.

I can try your suggestion but I've never attempted that before.

Comment: What I said about saving the data.. ignore that (after reading what you said in comment).  The keystrokes used for the binding are stored inside the .lnk (shortcut) and shouldn't change.. what is *probably* changing is in the end of your mouse and or hub.  Perhaps they remove and re-add the device on each boot?  I still stand by it probably being a problem with one of those devices and you doing something the developer didn't think of.  When you use the shortcut key section, does your (for instance) mouse #5 map to something like F10? .. or ??

Comment: BTW, The shortcut key internal part of the LNK file is REAL SIMPLE.  There isn't a lot to break.  It's [here](https://winprotocoldoc.blob.core.windows.net/productionwindowsarchives/MS-SHLLINK/%5bMS-SHLLINK%5d-210407.pdf) on page 17/18 of you want to get your geek suit on.

Comment: I use a lot of my keyboard so I had to get creative and use the numpad + shift/ctrl/alt, depending on what was free. The strange thing is that when I reboot my pc and try to use the macros after I've loaded Logitech's hub, it treats it as if there isn't a keystroke bound to the mouse button. It recognizes that something is being pressed but the keys themselves don't register as being bound to that batch file, so the file doesn't run until I rebind the key. However, manually clicking the file runs it just fine. https://i.imgur.com/jENcHWn.png It could be as you say, they didn't intend for this.

Comment: Small update. I had to update my graphics drivers and the delay set in after I restarted Windows. I've been putting up with it for a few days now but I just did something that fixed it. I changed the sound volume on a few applications with the Windows Volume Mixer. For whatever reason, this fixed the lag with my mouse keybind. This makes me think I may have a faulty program or malicious app running on my machine.